# How can I list the dependencies of a package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've downloaded the ROS Base and some other ROS packages.

Also, I've followed the doc http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source to install them.

Now I need to check which dependencies (so file) are used for each ROS package.

Is it possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288781/how-can-i-list-the-dependencies-of-a-package/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do this:

```
rospack depends [name of package]
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An alternative to `rospack depends` is [rqt_dep](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_dep) which visualizes the connections like so:

[image: image description]

The documentation for `rqt_dep` seems to be non-existent, but thankfully it is a simple interface so you can figure out what most options do through trial-and-error.

**Tip:** If you are using `rqt_dep` to show the dependencies for a package, make sure you source the workspace that contains that package first. Otherwise, when you type in your package name, nothing will show up.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6